# Problem deriving a user control from an abstract base class in website project

Tags: asp.net, user-controls, abstract-class, vs-web-site-project

In a Visual Studio website, I have created a user control.  This control is derived from a class (in App_Code) that is itself derived from System.Web.UI.UserControl.  This is an abstract class with an abstract method.  I then try to implement that method in the user control, but I get the following errors from Visual Studio:

```
Error   1   'WebUserControl.AbstractMethod()': no suitable method found to override C:\Users\User\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\WebSites\Delme\WebUserControl.ascx.cs    10  28  C:\...\Delme\    
Error   2   'WebUserControl' does not implement inherited abstract member 'AbstractBaseClass.AbstractMethod()'  c:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\delme\0eebaa86\f1a48678\App_Web_nrsbzxex.0.cs  14
```

Error 1 says that my override of the abstract method is invalid, it doesn't recognise the abstract method in the base class.  Error 2 says that the partial class automatically built by asp.net doesn't implement the abstract method!

Note that this works fine when the code is used in a Web Application project.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was that the abstract method in the base class was marked as **internal**.  While this is fine for web application projects where the classes all end up in the same assembly, a website does things differently. I guess the automatically created half of the partial class does not end up in the same assembly as my half, and so the internal keyword was breaking it.

Comment: Well generally speaking, abstract methods should be `protected`, so that only the *derived* classed can access/override the base methods.